Implementing drop-downs for docx.js.. is a Singleton necessary or a good idea at all here?
I am currently in the process of implementing drop-down lists for the docx.js library, which is written in Typescript, and I have a question about how to approach a specific part of this.
When you add a drop-down or similar in Word, it leads to a 'Glossary Document' being created in the underlying .docx bundle. This Glossary is only there when elements in the document that require it for proper functionality are present. Images added below to better visualize.


My question: What would be a sound approach for this? Considering that this Glossary directory/document is used for multiple elements like Combo Boxes. Date Pickers, etc. I'm struggling a bit to find the balance between not being too worried about future expansion and not being too short sighted with the task at hand.
Please be blunt and honest, I care about implementing something useful for a popular library and learning through collaboration, nothing more.
I have thought about adding a single GlossaryRegistry class that should be shared across, and to which the drop-down can register the elements/information necessary to add into the Glossary Document:
export class GlossaryRegistry {
    
    private static instance: GlossaryRegistry;
    private elements: RegisterableElement[] = [];

    private constructor(){}

    public static getInstance(): GlossaryRegistry {
        if (!GlossaryRegistry.instance) {
            GlossaryRegistry.instance = new GlossaryRegistry();
        }

        return GlossaryRegistry.instance;
    }

    public getElements(): readonly RegisterableElement[] | null {
        return this.elements;
    }

    public addElement(element: RegisterableElement): void {
        if (!this.elements) {
            this.elements = [element];
        }

        this.elements.push(element);
    }
}

export class DropDownList extends XmlComponent {
    public constructor(options?: readonly DropDownListOption[]){
        super("w:dropDownList");
        this.root.push(new listItem({
            displayText: "Choose an option",
            value: "Choose an option."
        })
        );
        if(options){
           options.forEach((listOption)=>{
            this.root.push(new listItem(listOption))
           })
        }

        // add information to Registry

    }
}

At the time of exporting, the corresponding class would check this Registry, and if there are elements, proceed to create the corresponding Glossary Document using the elements in the Registry.
Will keep an eye on this and edit accordingly.
